# Using Python to extract images and text from a word document

Tags: python, image, ms-word, extract, pywin32

I would like to run a script on a folder full of word documents that reads through the documents and pulls out images and their captions (text right below the images). From the research I've done, I think pywin32 might be a viable solution. I know how to use pywin32 to find strings and pull them out, but I need help with the images part. How can I read through a docx file and have an event occur when an image is found? Thank you for any help! I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4):

Docx files can be unzipped for extracting the images.

Answer (score 3):

Find some inspiration in this post [How can I search a word in a Word 2007 .docx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116139/how-can-i-read-a-word-2007-docx-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python module [docx2txt](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt) for extracting text as well as images from docx files

Answer (score -2):

```
document =docx.Document(filepath)
for image in document.inline_shapes:
    print (image.width, image.height)
```

Try this it will work.