# get text from docx in python

Tags: python, input, ms-word, python-docx

How can you get the text from a docx file in python? Preferably, this would import it to a simple string. Obviously formatting in the original file can be ignored.

I understand the structure of a docx file (a folder in which the text is saved as `document.xml`), but I would like a simple way of extracting the text, without having to manually open that folder, extract the file and extract paragraph tags.

I have tried [Python Docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) (as per [this old stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116139/how-can-i-read-a-word-2007-docx-file)), but get an error everytime:

```
import docx as dx
document = dx.opendocx('files/file.docx')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "concord.py", line 2, in <module>
    document = dx.opendocx('files/#n01 ch B3A126.docx')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'opendocx'
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a file named `docx.py` in the current directory?

Comment: No I don't have `docx.py` in the current working directory. However, there is such a file in `Python Docx` github release. To install it, all I did was extract it to a random folder (which I since deleted) and ran `python setup.py install`. Hope that's ok?

Comment: What do you get if you put `dir(dx)` right after the import?

Comment: If I do it in iPython I get: `Out[2]: 
['AdvSearch',
 'Image',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 'advReplace',
 'appproperties',
 'clean',
 'contenttypes',
 'coreproperties',
 'etree',
 'findTypeParent',
 'getdocumenttext',
 'heading',
 'join',
 'log',
 'logging',
 'makeelement',
 'newdocument',
 'nsprefixes',
 'opendocx',
 'os',
 'pagebreak',
 'paragraph',
 'picture',
 're',
 'relationshiplist',
 'replace',
 'savedocx',
 'search',
 'shutil',
 'table',
 'template_dir',
 'time',
 'websettings',
 'wordrelationships',
 'zipfile']
`

Comment: If I do it as I originally was, in a text editor (notepad++) and run the file from the command line using `python filename.py`, I get `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`.. Not sure why I get different results running python and running it directly in iPython..

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://davidmburke.com/2014/02/04/python-convert-documents-doc-docx-odt-pdf-to-plain-text-without-libreoffice/). The author of this blog has written 2 functions, one converts a odt/doc/docx to pdf, the next reads plain text from the thus created pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind discarding the formatting and you simply want to extract the text, you can open the `.docx` as a zip file and then strip the XML tags using regular expressions:

```py
import re
import zipfile

def extract_text(filepath):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath) as docx:
        content = docx.read('word/document.xml').decode('utf-8')
        return re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', content)
```