# Getting the Headers of PDF file, from the contents of body

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Dermatology**
A dermatologist is a physician with training and expertise in the diagnosis and medical/surgical management of diseases of the skin,  hair and nails, and mucous membranes.

**Gynecology**
An obstetrician/gynecologist focuses on the health of women before, during, and after pregnancy, diagnosing and treating conditions of the reproductive system and associated disorders

Please consider the above information are present in a PDF file. My job is to retrieve the Specialty (**Dermatology/Gynecology**) based on the matching of fields like (*Skin, pregnancy*). Any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? Googling PDF parsing in Python returns many results...[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com) Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Most of the suggestions were for using PDFMINER. But, I am not sure if pdfminer supports Python 3x. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 different lists of words specific to Dermatology, Gynecology respectively like this:

```
dermatology_list = ["skin", "hair", "nails"]
gynecology_list = ["women", "pregnancy", "reproductive"]
```

Start with a `score = 0`, Parse the PDF file one word at a time, if the word is in Dermatology-list `score += 1` if the word is in Gynecology-list `score -= 1`. At the end, if the score is **positive** your answer is **Dermatology**, and if the score is ***negative*** the answer is ***Gynecology***. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860635/python-parsing-files-docx-pdf-and-odt-and-converting-the-content-into-my-d) should help you with parsing the PDF and extracting the data.