# Loading text from .docx to MySQL using Python-docx

Tags: python, mysql, docx, python-docx

As of now, I am using Python-docx to convert the text in a .docx file into a single string.

```
f = open(os.path.expanduser("~/documents/myFile.docx"))

document = opendocx(f)

docString = ''.join(getdocumenttext(document))
```

I am then parsing the string using simple built-in Python split methods.
Once the string is parsed into a list, I am loading that list into a MySQL database. This works great, but my only problem is I want to preserve the special characters.

The database supports these special character (utf-8) but a lot of characters and formatting (italics, bold, etc.) are lost when I convert the .docx into a string.

I want to be able to parse and load text with the formatting intact from the .docx file.

Comment: If you need to put it into the db, it is probably not possible to preserve italics, bolding, etc.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of storing the files in db with formatting? Why not store the path to a docx file in the string instead?

Comment: The files arent being stored in the db. Components (text) of the .docx are stored in the database, and it is important that these components maintain their formatting

Comment: Rereading my question, that isnt clear

Comment: I am still unclear what your purpose for doing this is.
When you say formatting, do you mean you just want to preserve Italic or Bold text or is there additional layout information that you want to presever? What format are you hoping to use keep this in in the MySQL db - rtf, html, markdown?