# Remove all italicized characters from the first column of a docx table in Python

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

All I could find was [about paragraphs as wholes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740731/reading-docx-files-recognizing-and-storing-italicized-text) (as it seems). Tried to use the solution anyway, but there was an error ("AttributeError: .runs").

I looked into [python-docx documentation](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/styles-using.html), but I don't know how to apply that information here.

My paragraphs have italicized words and possibly parts of words. What (I think) I need is a loop that checks if characters are italicized.

```
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
word.Documents.Open("C:**path**.docx")
doc = word.ActiveDocument

doc.Tables.Count

table = doc.Tables(1)   

index = list(range(0, 1000))

for i in index: 
    s = table.Cell(Row =i, Column =1).Range.Text  
    # now another loop, using 'run' object?
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `docx` module.

Comment: Can't import Document from docx (ImportError: cannot import name Document)

Comment: Did you use `pip install docx`? This would give you an old version. Try `python-docx`instead.

Comment: Same error. Thought Python 3 wasn't supported, but looks like it is.

Comment: what is the value of `docx.__version__`?

Comment: 0.2.4. I got this information from pip list.

Comment: Have you noticed that the documentation you linked is for version 0.8.5?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `docx`, but maybe you have a version problem.

The documentation you linked in your question is for python-docx 0.8.5.

On pypi there is a [docx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx) module, which seems to be outdated as the highest available version is 0.2.4.

There is another module called [python-docx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-docx), which looks more recent (versions up to 0.8.5).

If you used pip to install docx, you can update to python-docx, which should give you the newest version:

```
> pip uninstall docx
> pip install python-docx
```

Comment: I have python-docx installed, too. 0.8.5. Can an outdated docx module interfere with python-docx?

Comment: I think so. They use the same module name - I'm not sure which of them is loaded on runtime, or maybe they overwrite each other on installation. Best remove the old one and reinstall python-docx.

Comment: Yes. The two will interfere with each other because they share the same module name ("docx"), even though they have different package names ("python-docx" vs "docx"). Which one you get when you `import ... from docx` may depend on the order in which they were installed, but in any case is a crap shoot. In general, python-docx is a new version of the legacy docx package, but is a complete rewrite (object-oriented) and the two APIs are not compatible (not even a little bit :).