# UnicodeDecodeError for Reading files in Python

Tags: python

```
pythonNotes = open('E:\\Python Notes.docx','r')
read_it_now = pythonNotes.read()
print(read_it_now.encode('utf-16'))
```

When I try this code, I get:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' can't decode byte 0x8f in position 591 character maps to <undefined>`

I am running this in visual studio with python tools - starting without debugging.

I have tried putting `enc='utf-8'` at the top, throwing it in as a parameter, I've looked at other questions and just couldn't find a solution to this simple issue.

Please assist.

Comment: Did you try `open('E:\\Python Notes.docx','r', encoding='utf-8')` (note `encoding`, not `enc`)? Also, which version of Python are you using?

Comment: A .docx file is a binary file, so you aren't going to be able to print anything coherent without more work.  You could open it in binary mode (`'rb'`) and use the `zipfile` module to extract the XML data inside.

Comment: hey aurora that enconding='utf-8' does not work, and mark, would that be rb instead of r? i think i found some site that showed how to do the XML, i can try that

Answer (score 0):

This error [can occur](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-double-conversion.html) when text that is already in utf-8 format is read in as an 8-bit encoding, and python tries to "decode" it to Unicode: Bytes that have no meaning in the supposed encoding throw a `UnicodeDecodeError`. But you'll always get an error if you try to read a file as `utf-8` that is not in the `utf-8` encoding.

In your case, the problem is that a docx file is not a regular text file; no single text encoding can meaningfully import it. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/116217/699305) for directions on how to read it on a low level, or use [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get access to the document in a way that resembles what you see in Word.